# How to configure Salesforce Chatter App in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I need to integrate Salesforce chatter to SharePoint Online. I have added the Chatter app in my Site collection from SharePoint Store. But after adding the Chatter web part on the Page, it is asking for configure the chatter, i have created the Salesforce trial account also, but it seems to some different thing i need to configure, has some one done this already, Could you please suggest to achieve this.